# How to use epoll in rust

Tags: rust, epoll

I came across [this](https://docs.rs/epoll/4.1.0/epoll/) library to support `epoll` in rust but I'm not sure how to properly use the `epoll:wait` function:

```
let mut events = [Event; 10];
rc = epoll::wait(self.vfio_epoll_fd, timeout, &mut events)?;
```

Would be nice if someone could provide me with some examples to get started :) Thanks in advance for your support.

I get the following error when compiling the above code:

```
error[E0423]: expected value, found struct `Event`
   --> src/interrupts.rs:132:27
    |
132 |         let mut events = [Event; 10];
    |                           ^^^^^ did you mean `Event { /* fields */ }`?
```

Event structure looks like this:

```
pub struct Event {
    pub events: Events,
    pub data: u64,
}
```

The problem is I don't know what `Events` as it is a bitflag.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @mcarton How do I define the events array?

Comment: What happens with the code you have shown? Does it fail to compile? With what message? Does it fail to run? With what message? Does it run but not do what you expected? What did you expect and what does it do?

Comment: @Jmb See updated answer

Comment: `as it is a bitflag` - it is not a bitflag, it is a structure. Did you check out the [reference](https://docs.rs/epoll/4.1.0/epoll/struct.Events.html)?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes I saw it but if I look at my source code it looks like this:
`bitflags! { pub struct Events: u32 { ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since `events` is an output parameter for `epoll::wait` you can put anything in there, but you need to put a valid value. A sensible default would be an empty event set:

```
let mut events = [Event::empty(); 10];
```

`Events` is a struct generated by the `bitflags` macro, so looking at the source code won't help much in understanding how to use it, but luckily `bitflags` also generates quite comprehensive [documentation](https://docs.rs/epoll/4.1.0/epoll/struct.Events.html) for the generated structs.

Comment: Doesn't work for me I get a `function or associated item not found in 'epoll::Event'` on `Event::empty()`

Comment: ok found the solution now: `let mut events = [Event::new(Events::empty(), 0); 10];` Thanks for your support :)